# Bootstrap checkboxes and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap check boxes which don't seem to behave the same way as normal check boxes.   Looking on other posts, it seems bootstrap check boxes return a value of undefined so using a if checked does not work.

Code:

```
<div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
  <input id="homeaddress" type="checkbox" checked>
    <label for="homeaddress">
      Same As My Home Address
    </label>
</div>
<div id="show-hide-address">
  content
</div>



$("#show-hide-address").hide();
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#homeaddress").on("click", function(){
        if ($(this).attr("checked")==undefined) { 
               $('#show-hide-address').slideUp();  // checked  
            } else {
               $('#show-hide-address').slideDown();  // unchecked
            }
    });
});
```

When the page loads the checkbox is checked and the content div is invisible as it should be.   When I un-check it, the content div does slide down as it should.  BUT when I click the checkbox again, the slide up does not work, nothing happens.  Has anyone dealt with this before.  Am I missing something?  Thanks,

UPDATE:  added a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/gj3w046f/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$('#homeaddress').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('#show-hide-address').slideUp();
  } else {
    $('#show-hide-address').slideDown();
  }
});
```

here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jx3yL4o4/198/)

Comment: That worked.  not sure why bootstrap checkboxes seem so complex.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you are checking the attribute. Use this:

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

Comment: Tried it.  Same result.

Comment: You need to change your javscript load type in the fiddle panel to domready not onload